# (AS3 & PHP) sending multiple values from php to flash

Tags: php, mysql, database, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to send multiple values from PHP to Flash. I know how to send back one value, and that's by using PHP's `print` or `echo`, and then in flash using `e.target.data.`, for example...

PHP:

```
print "resultMessage=$something";
```

Flash:

```
var resultText:TextField;
resultText.text = e.target.data.resultMessage;
```

The problem is when trying to receive 2 values; I've tried things like...

PHP:

```
print "resultNumber=$somethingNumber";
print "resultName=$somethingName";
```

Flash:

```
var flashNumber:TextField
flashNumber.text = e.target.data.resultNumber;
var flashName:TextField;
flashName.text = e.target.data.resultName;
```

But when I try that, `flashNumber` would end up as flashNumber and flashName mashed together, like `2Tom or 7Mary` or something like that.
I tried printing `<br>` between the 2 values in PHP, but I still got the same result. I know that I can split the PHP into 2 PHP files and get a value from each one, but that would be a little ridiculous, since in my program I'll need to get many values.

Is there another way to send values from PHP to Flash, so that I can send more than 1 value? Or, is there a way to use `print` or `echo` to send more than 1 value?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by outputting your data in a standard URL encoded variable format.  (You need the ampersand that applications use to separate variables - otherwise it thinks everything after the first = is the value)

eg:    `print "resultNumber=$somethingNumber&resultName=$somethingName";`

Then AS3 should automatically work the way you are trying.

---

You could also ouput XML or JSON as suggested by someone else.

**JSON**

PHP

```
<?php
$arr = array(somethingName, somethingNumber);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

AS3

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(e.target.data);
trace(jsonObj.somethingName, jsonObj.somethingNumber);
```

---

**XML**

PHP

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<data>
 <somethingName>
  blah blah blah
 </somethingName>
 <somethingNumber>
  12345
 </somethingNumber>
</data>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

echo $xml->asXML();

?>
```

AS3

```
myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
trace(myXML.somethingName, myXML.somethingNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, I thought using an ampersand would throw me an error like using a comma did...I'll also keep the JSON and XML methods in mind in case. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Better use some data formatting instead of passing data as pure text - XML or JSON is a good idea.

Comment: Please consider updating your answer to be more useful. As it is it's more of a comment and doesn't actually show how do anything